# Grails: Reference Two Models in One View

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

As mentioned in my previous post, I'm working on a small Grails CRUD app. In my app I have a "Master Agreement" model that has a hasMany relationship with a model called "SOW" (scope of work). I have a view called "show" under Master Agreeements that shows the administrative information for the selected Master Agreement. At the bottom of the page I would like to show each SOW associated with the master agreement. Below is my code along with the actions I've taken to try and solve this.

Show Action in Master Agreement Controller:

The Master Agreement model is successfully passed to the Master Agreement "show" view and Grails successfully prints the sowList to the console. However, when I reference the SOW model in the view, nothing happens.

```
   def show(Long id){
    println 'I made it to show for Master Agreement.'
    def masterAgreementInstance = MasterAgreement.get(id)
    def sowList = masterAgreementInstance.getSows()
    println sowList

    render(view: "show", model: [masterAgreement: masterAgreementInstance, sow: sowList])
}
```

Master Agreement "Show" View

The HTML is rather long, so below is how I reference the Master Agreement model (this works), followed by how I am trying to reference the SOW model (this doesn't work - the page loads, but nothing happens with the sow reference).  In fact, no rows show up at all under my table headers.

```
<div class="grid-item">
   <div class="label">Office:</div>
   <div class="data">${masterAgreement.office.name}</div>
</div>
```

Unsuccessful SOW Model Reference - (see ${sow.name} and ${sow.spendCap} )

```
<table class="infoTable fullWidth">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>SOW Name</th>
        <th>Invoice Total</th>
        <th>SOW Amount</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th class="centered">Expand</th>
    </tr>

    <g:each status="i" var="sow" in="${sow}">
        <tr>
            <td>${i + 1}</td> 
            <td>${sow.name}</td>
            <td>Placeholder data</td>
            <td>${sow.spendCap}</td>
            <td>
                <g:link controller="SOW" action="show">View</g:link>
            </td>
            <td class="centered">
                <i class="fas fa-angle-left" id="expandArrow" onclick="expandInvoices();" title="Expand Invoices"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>

</table>
```

Below are the two models.

```
class MasterAgreement {
String name
String pointOfContactFName
String pointOfContactLName
String pointOfContactPhone
String pointOfContactEmail
Double spendCap
Date   startDate
Date   endDate
Office office  
BidType bidType  
MasterAgreementStatus masterAgreementStatus  

static hasMany = [sows: SOW]
static belongsTo = [contractor: Contractor]  //will cascade on Contractor delete

static constraints = {

}
```

}

```
class SOW {
String name
Double spendCap


static hasMany = [sowInvoices: SOWInvoice]
static belongsTo = [masterAgreement: MasterAgreement]  //will cascade on Contractor and/or MasterAgreement delete

static constraints = {

}
```

}

How the page looks upon loading. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxSbV.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the each loop you're using the same name for the list and the instance for the loop (`sow`) - try changing the var to something unique.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you.